Tarzan like character on AXN India channel
Out of blue I remembered a series shown on "AXN-India" approximately 6 years ago. 
The hero was like Tarzan living in a jungle. 
He had two squirrels in his satchel. He had an eagle friend watching from the sky. And he could see the view from sky thorough the eagles eyes.
I think that's all I can remember. I'm not able to recollect the serial's name, can you?

The description you provide also fits the Beastmaster http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beastmaster_(film) which spawned several sequels and a TV series.  He had two ferrets he carried in a bag, an eagle who's eyes he could see through, and a tiger.... but he has often been compared more to Conan than Tarzan.

@BonGart That sounds pretty much like the answer, make it one (referring to the TV-show directly).

@ChristianRau done.  I provided a wikipedia link to the TV show as well

It sounds like you might be thinking of The Beastmaster.  It not only comes in a few different movie flavors, but also spawned a TV series.  Dar, the hero, carries a pair of ferrets in a bag, has an eagle companion which he can use to see through it's eyes, and a tiger companion as well.

ohh yes ... Thank you very much.
